# Kafka MirrorMaker crashing frequently

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-mirrormaker

We have mirror-maker running on docker container which is orchestrated by kubernetes. We see very frequent crashes for our mirror maker pod when the input load is huge (assumption).

- producer.config

```
batch.size = 100000
buffer.memory = 50000000
compression.type = gzip
linger.ms = 100
retries=1000
max.request.size = 1000000
acks=1
max.in.flight.requests.per.connection = 5
```

- consumer.config

```
auto.offset.reset=earliest
partition.assignment.strategy=org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.RoundRobinAssignor
```

- `ERROR` Level Logs:

```
rg.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Expiring 817 record(s) for xxxTopic-21: 33484 ms has passed since last append
2020-06-16 03:36:28 INFO  MirrorMaker$:72 - Closing producer due to send failure.
2020-06-16 03:36:28 INFO  KafkaProducer:341 - [Producer clientId=producer-1] Closing the Kafka producer with timeoutMillis = 0 ms.
2020-06-16 03:36:28 INFO  KafkaProducer:341 - [Producer clientId=producer-1] Proceeding to force close the producer since pending requests could not be completed within timeout 0 ms.
2020-06-16 03:36:28 ERROR ErrorLoggingCallback:52 - Error when sending message to topic xxxTopic with key: null, value: 173 bytes with error:
org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Expiring 817 record(s) for xxxTopic-21: 33484 ms has passed since last append
2020-06-16 03:36:28 INFO  MirrorMaker$:72 - Closing producer due to send failure.
2020-06-16 03:36:28 INFO  KafkaProducer:341 - [Producer clientId=producer-1] Closing the Kafka producer with timeoutMillis = 0 ms.
2020-06-16 03:36:28 INFO  KafkaProducer:341 - [Producer clientId=producer-1] Proceeding to force close the producer since pending requests could not be completed within timeout 0 ms.
2020-06-16 03:36:28 ERROR ErrorLoggingCallback:52 - Error when sending message to topic xxxTopic with key: null, value: 201 bytes with error:
org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Expiring 817 record(s) for xxxTopic-21: 33484 ms has passed since last append
```

- And the pod crashes after the `FATAL` level log preceeded with the `ERROR` logs mentioned above:

```
org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Expiring 731 record(s) for xxxTopic-22: 30117 ms has passed since batch creation plus linger time
2020-06-16 03:36:44 FATAL MirrorMaker$MirrorMakerThread:120 - [mirrormaker-thread-0] Mirror maker thread failure due to
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot send after the producer is closed.
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.RecordAccumulator.append(RecordAccumulator.java:198)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer.doSend(KafkaProducer.java:806)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer.send(KafkaProducer.java:760)
    at kafka.tools.MirrorMaker$MirrorMakerProducer.send(MirrorMaker.scala:711)
--
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterable.foreach(Iterable.scala:54)
    at kafka.tools.MirrorMaker$MirrorMakerThread.run(MirrorMaker.scala:431)
2020-06-16 03:36:44 INFO  MirrorMaker$:72 - Closing producer due to send failure.
2020-06-16 03:36:44 INFO  KafkaProducer:341 - [Producer clientId=producer-1] Closing the Kafka producer with timeoutMillis = 0 ms.
2020-06-16 03:36:44 INFO  KafkaProducer:341 - [Producer clientId=producer-1] Proceeding to force close the producer since pending requests could not be completed within timeout 0 ms.
2020-06-16 03:36:44 FATAL MirrorMaker$MirrorMakerThread:120 - [mirrormaker-thread-1] Mirror maker thread failure due to
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot send after the producer is closed.
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.RecordAccumulator.append(RecordAccumulator.java:198)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer.doSend(KafkaProducer.java:806)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer.send(KafkaProducer.java:760)
    at kafka.tools.MirrorMaker$MirrorMakerProducer.send(MirrorMaker.scala:711)
```

*Version*:

1.0.0 Kafka Client.

Comment: Which docker image are you using? Why not use MirrorMaker2?

Comment: But we can't upgrade to MM 2. So do you have any idea on why it's happening?

Comment: You say you're using Docker, so why cannot you just switch to a different container? What about upgrading the client version? Again, which Docker image are you using? Also, if the producer thread stops, you need to restart the container anyway, as the mirroring isn't working. You should enable debug logs to determine the cause